# Change font of output console in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ide

I'm a beginner programmer using visual basic on visual studio working mostly with Consoles, and I would like to change the font size of the text that the compiler outputs displays when the code is compiled (not the text when I'm coding, those are fine). Here's what it looks like, compare it to the exit, minimise buttons and the file directory on the title bar for size references

Right now, the font size is like 8pt which is annoying.

Comment: Please write something more and clear, you can also provide screen shots or examples for more detail.

Comment: @HareshAmbaliya the wording is no issue to me. Though it could be reworded to be easier to understand.

Answer (score 50):

Open the options window and go to the <kbd>Fonts and Colors</kbd> item. Select the window you'd like to change and then change the font-size to your liking:

[image]

You'll likely need to change multiple items, since each window uses its own settings:

- Output Window
- Command Window
- Immediate Window

And possibly others.

[image]

To change the font size of the console that launches when you debug an application, you need to change the default font size for the windows console.

Start a command-prompt and then open the options screen

[image]

Set the font size:

[image]

This will apply to all consoles that open in the future.

Comment: this did not work. I changed the fonts for Command Window, Immediate Window and Output Window, all from 9pt to 21pt, but when I ran it the displayed font was still minuscule. I tried saving, closing the solution and re-opening it but this still didnt work.

Comment: What's the title of the window you want the font-size increased of?

Comment: this is hard to answer since I'm not allowed to post a picture yet due to credit restrictions or the something similar, and I cant remember what that image was like, must have been something along the lines of C:\users\<username>\desktop\<filename>

Comment: For anyone needing the Test Explorer Output... you need to change the font settings for `Environment`. Sadly this does change the appearance of the whole application.

Comment: I don't know about the OP, but this did help me.  The 'Output' window is not the same as a "Console Window".  One is part of Visual Studio, Debug.WriteLine () uses it. as a Console.WriteLine goes to an actual console window.  I have a WinForm that I want to see the log window while it's not being shown.  This let me see those messages.   I have a Conditional build it to do this while under VS, and not otherwise.   It was the font size I was able to change, that's all that was needed.

Comment: If I am using `windows terminal :Microsoft Visual Studio Debug`, where should I make the settings like in the picture? I can't find

Answer (score 7):

None of the solutions suggested by jessehouwing worked for me (using Visual Studio 2017).

What did work was running a console program to open the console, clicking the small icon on the left in the title bar of the console window, clicking properties, fonts, and chosing the preferred font size.

Comment: This suggestion was actually in of that answer.  But that answer was actually two different suggestions and this was the latter one, so I missed it there and actually noticed it here first.

Comment: The second suggestion in jessehouwings answer was to open a windows command prompt window and change the default settings from there. This did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

After running and seeing the console windows,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In VSC 2019 go to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Features -> Terminal and find option of font-size and change to apropriate value for your needs.Question isnt really clear what you exactly need but for all settings of font-size-s is pretty the same path to the solution.